# Enabling mongo authentication by ansible playbook

Tags: mongodb, ansible

I trying install mongodb on my server and enable authentication. But I'm stuck on adding user for auth. When I try execute playbook it fails on **Add user** task with output:

> An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: there are no users authenticated
>   fatal: [***]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "unable to connect to database: there are no users authenticated"}

How can I fix it?

**playbook.yml**

```
- name: Install mongodb
  apt:
    name: mongodb-org
    update_cache: yes
    state: present

- name: Set config
  template:
    src: templates/mongodb.yml
    dest: /etc/mongod.conf
  notify: restart mongodb

- name: Install pymongo
  pip:
    name: pymongo
    state: present

- name: Add user
  mongodb_user:
    database: "{{ mongodb_name }}"
    name: "{{ mongodb_user }}"
    password: "{{ mongodb_password }}"
    login_host: "{{ mongodb_bind_ip }}"
    login_port: "{{ mongodb_port }}"
    state: present
```

**mongodb.yml**

```
net:
  port: {{ mongodb_port }}
  bindIp: {{ mongodb_bind_ip }}
  unixDomainSocket:
   enabled: false
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have admin user in the database you need to start it with disabled `security.authorization`, add admin user, then restart mongodb with enabled `security.authorization` : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/#procedure

After that you can add more users using admin's credentials:

```
- name: Add user
  mongodb_user:
    database: "{{ mongodb_name }}"
    name: "{{ mongodb_user }}"
    password: "{{ mongodb_password }}"
    login_host: "{{ mongodb_bind_ip }}"
    login_port: "{{ mongodb_port }}"
    login_user: "{{ admin_login }}"
    login_password: "{{ admin_password }}"
    state: present
```

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/mongodb_user_module.html